# What is the difference between Facebook start_time in Events table and on FB event page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm using [explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to test this [event](https://www.facebook.com/events/359724487410779)

FQL to [Event table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/) : fql?q={'events': 'select eid, name, start_time from event where eid = 359724487410779'} - returns start_time = 1337410800 
Converting 1337410800 gives Saturday, May 19th 2012, 07:00:00 (GMT)

Event object in FB api explorer: https://graph.facebook.com/359724487410779 - returns start_time = 2012-05-19T00:00:00

Event object in browser: https://graph.facebook.com/359724487410779 - returns start_time = 2012-05-18T14:00:00

FB page https://www.facebook.com/events/359724487410779 - Friday, May 18, 2012
11:00pm until 4:00am in UTC+02

How can I get the right local time, like on FB Event page (Friday, May 18, 2012
11:00pm) based on Facebook API ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Event table - it contains time of the event (in GMT) if it would be in Pacific zone (see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/)) - so 1337410800 will give you May 19th 7am in GMT -> which is May 18th 11pm in PST - which is the time of the event if you remove timezone.
2. Event object in FB api explorer - it returns time converted to YOUR Facebook profile time zone - which gives me 2012-05-18T17:00:00 for example (EST). Again, this converts to May 18th 11pm in CET
3. Event object in browser - i.e. direct call to FB API - gives you start time in PST time zone (2pm PST -> 11pm in Europe/Amsterdam timezone)
4. FB page obviously have LOCAL time

**Answering your question** - personally I would go with Graph API call and will convert **start_time** from Pacific into UTC. Then use "**timezone: Europe/Amsterdam**" to convert UTC time into local time.